# Increasing the font size of only 1 axis value in an R plot

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering how I can **increase the font size** of ONLY number **"6"** in my x-axis in the plot below? (**Please see my R code below**)

[image]

**Here is my R code:**

```
plot(1:10, ty = 'n', ann = F, xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')

axis(side = 1, at = 1:10, font = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `cex.axis` in another `axis` call exclusively for number 6.

```
plot(1:10, ty = 'n', ann = F, xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
axis(side = 1, at = c(1:5,7:10), font = 2)
axis(side = 1, at = 6, , font = 2, cex.axis=2)
```

[image]

**EDIT** To move the 6 lower as requested, use `line`:

```
plot(1:10, ty = 'n', ann = F, xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
axis(side = 1, at = c(1:5,7:10), font = 2)
axis(side=1, at = 6, labels=FALSE,tick=TRUE) #draw normal tick, no label
axis(side = 1, at = 6, , font = 2, cex.axis=2, line=0.5,tick = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but "6" has gone so close to the tick mark can we bring it down a bit?

Comment: @parvinkarimi try `cex.axis=1.5`

Comment: So, I want to keep the size of "6", just want the distance to decrease!

Comment: Actually, I found a better option: `plot(1:10, ty = 'n', ann = F, xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n');
axis(side = 1, at = c(1:5, 7:10), font = 2);
axis(side = 1, at = 6, font = 2, cex.axis = 2, mgp = c(3, 1.25, 0) )`, but many thanks I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
plot(1:10, ty = 'n', ann = F, xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
axis(1, 1:10, labels = NA)
mtext(text = "6", side = 1, line = 1, at = 6, cex = 3, font = 2, padj = 0.5)
mtext(text = paste(c(1:5,7:10)), side = 1, line = 1,
                        at = c(1:5,7:10), cex = 1, font = 2, padj = 0.5)
```